# Why i am getting this output while printing numbers numbers of a particular interval

Tags: java

I am trying to print the the numbers in between particular intervals by taking starting, ending interval range of a particular interval but I am not able to get the correct output.

I am using Scanner class to take input from user.
I have used start1, start2 and end1, end2 of 2 intervals to show their starting and ending range.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Smallest234Number
{
    public static void smallest2NoInterval(int p[],int x[])  
    {
        System.out.println("First interval");

        for(int k=0;k<p.length;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(p[k++]);
        }
        System.out.println("Second Interval");

        for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(x[k++]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ar1[]=new int[10];
        int ar2[]=new int[10];

        int i=0;
        int s=0;

        // i have taken 2 intervals for a base
        System.out.println("Enter the first Interval");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first of starting interval");
        int startno1=sc.nextInt();
        //now take input from user startno

        System.out.println("Enter the end of  starting interval");
        int endno1=sc.nextInt();
        //now take input from user endno

        System.out.println("Enter the second interval");
        System.out.println("Enter the first of Second interval");
        int startno2=sc.nextInt();

        //now take input of 2Interval  from user startno1

        System.out.println("Enter the end of Second interval");
        int endno2=sc.nextInt();

        //now take input of 2Interval  from user endno1

        System.out.println("Enter the first interval nos only between start   no and end no");

        System.out.println("Enter the first interval nos only between   start no and end no");

       for(int a=startno1;a<=endno1;a++)
       {
            int inputNo=sc.nextInt();


            if(inputNo<=endno1&&inputNo>=startno1)
            {
                ar1[s]=inputNo;
                s++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the Second interval nos only between start no1 and end no1");

       for(int a=startno2;a<=endno2;a++)
       {
            int inputNo=sc.nextInt();


            if(inputNo<=endno1&&inputNo>=startno1)
            {
                ar2[i]=inputNo;
                i++;
             }

        }
        smallest2NoInterval(ar1,ar2);
    }
}

**Output Shown:**

Enter the first Interval
Enter the first of starting interval
1
Enter the end of  starting interval
3
Enter the second interval
Enter the first of Second interval
2
Enter the end of Second interval
4
Enter the first interval nos only between start no and end no
Enter the first interval nos only between start no and end no
1
2
3
Enter the Second interval nos only between start no1 and end no1
2
3
4
First interval
1
3
0
0
0
Second interval
2
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: i do not understand what you want to do exactly, but if you only want to enter start and end, and then print out the whole interval, then you should not use the scanner (sc.nextInt()) anymore after you know start and end. it also looks like you would be better off using `ArrayList<Integer>` (generally recommended and more flexible, also has a dynamic size) instead of `int[]`.

Comment: also consider writing just one function for scanning start and end, and one function for outputting an interval, and call each of these function 2 times.
also think about whether you may only need to store start and end, instead of all numbers, and only generate the numbers right when you output them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using same variable `i` for indexing in both the arrays `ar1` and `ar2` that's why your program puts integers on first two places in `ar1` and than 3rd place in `ar2`. You shall use different index variables or reset `i=0` just before putting values in `ar2`.

**EDIT**
Another problem is in your printing logic

```
for(int k=0;k<p.length;k++)
{
    System.out.println(p[k++]);
}
System.out.println("Second Interval");

for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++)
{
    System.out.println(x[k++]);
}
```

you are incrementing index variable twice in the loop Please correct it like this:

```
for(int k=0;k<p.length;k++)
{
    System.out.println(p[k]);
}
System.out.println("Second Interval");

for(int k=0;k<x.length;k++)
{
    System.out.println(x[k]);
}
```

Comment: it surely will produce different result please update code in question itself.

Comment: I am Sorry the result was Different that time and yes i got the result.Did some silly mistakes.Thanku

Comment: Glad that helped you. Have fun coding :)